# how do we deploy ear file in IBM WAS from CMD/PowerShell/Linux terminal

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8, websphere-7, websphere-portal

how to deploy the war/ear file in IBM WebSphere Application Server from cmd/PowerShell/Linux terminal?

I had installed the IBM WebSphere Application Server in my local machine.
Then it ran properly. And also checked the UI by using below URL.

```
https://localhost:9443/ibm/console/
```

Comment: You can do it using `wsadmin` tool - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=scripting-commands-adminapp-object-using-wsadmin#rxml_adminapp__cmd7